# Is it possible to get parent function name in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, class

```
class B{

  constructor()
    // how to determine the function name in which this object was created?
  }

}


function a(){
  let b = new B();

}
```

In the constructor of B I need to find out in which function it was called. I want the function name, which is `a` in the given example.

Is this possible with js?

Comment: While there may be some contorted way of doing that (which may not always work, for example when the calling function has no name), it's absolutely not idiomatic JavaScript practice to do that. It would probably help a lot if you describe why you would want to do something like that.

Comment: This seems to be a pretty clear XY problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: This is almost certainly an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Oh also, the term "parent" is not really a good term for "function in which a constructor is invoked".  There's no relationship between the function containing the `new` expression and the constructed object, other than the reference to the new object being part of the closure.

Comment: Parse the Coke into an AST, then find the desired method and look up its parent in the tree hierarchy?

Comment: it's certainly not a XY problem. I have a list of functions that do different type of file operations and I just think it's nicer to automatically find out the name of the operation instead of passing in the arguments.

Comment: @Alex Sounds like an architectural/design problem that's either missing an abstraction layer or a pattern, which in turns makes it sound like an XY problem. The point is, besides that any solution other than parsing source code just won't work reliably, is that this is better wrapped up in something that'll actually work consistently.

Answer (score 3):

create an Error and use its stack;

```
function foo() {
  var err = new Error();
  var stack = err.stack; // This is an array of stack frames
}
```

Comment: As Pointy pointed, this solution is frought given anonymous functions, transpilation, obfuscation, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Error.stack...

```js
class B {

  constructor() {
    // how to determine the function name in which this object was created?
    const ex = new Error()
    console.log('call from [', ex.stack.split('\n')[2].trim().split(' ')[1], ']');

  }

}

function a() {
  let b = new B();

}

function helloWorld() {
  let b = new B();

}


a();
helloWorld();
```

Comment: Same comment as on the earlier answer: this will not work reliably.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, with `arguments.callee.caller.name`.

Comment: `arguments.callee, caller, ...` are not accessible if you are in strict mode.